Decision of emulation type for Cortex A | QEMU vs Fast-modle
I hope you'll be able to throw in some words to help me decide what best suits me.
I work on a bring up of a CPU, consiting of ARM Cortex-A, supporting the newest (or almost the newest) ARMv9+.
I am planning to use TF-A to get myself going with the El3 firmware developing, and now I am currently doubting how to best simulate the Cortex-A processor.
qemu-system-aarch64 --cpu help doesn't give me the specific cortex-a CPU I intend to work with - The newest I see there is cortex-a72 which is ARMv8.
Thus, I started considering using fast-modles.
Is there anyone experienced with any of QEMU or fast-modles and can share from his/her experience what is more suited?
How much efforts will it require?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
P.S If anyone also knows the difference between QEMU --machine and --cpu it might also be useful.
What's the difference between specifying the CPU or the virtual machine?
